# Spring security show login every time

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to permit all users for tags page, but app keeps login page every time.
Here is my config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringBootSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("root").password("{noop}password").roles("admin");
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http 
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/tags").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("admin")
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();

    }
}
```

Some methods from controller

```
     @GetMapping("/tags") 
     public String showAllTags(Model model) {
         
         model.addAttribute("tags", tagRepository.findAll());
         
         return "all_tags";
         
     }
     
     @GetMapping("/admin/edit/tag/{id}")
     public String showUpdateForm(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model) {
         Tag tag = tagRepository.findById(id)
           .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid user Id:" + id));
         
         model.addAttribute("tag", tag);
         return "update_tag";
     }
     
     @PostMapping("/admin/update/tag/{id}")
        public String updateTag(@PathVariable("id") long id, Tag tag, 
          BindingResult result, Model model) {
            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                tag.setId(id);
                return "update_tag";
            }

            tagRepository.save(tag);
            return "redirect:/tags";
        }
```

Actually, it looks like my disabled security not working at all. When I am accessing to /tags it shows Login page.

Comment: can u put all_tags.html content in your question description.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below security dependency in pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
<version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: through the way you define your controller  and services

Comment: I don't understand, what's wrong with configuration? Should "permitAll" provide no authentication way?